# Symfony2 Doctrine Migration --em inside the migration file

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration, entity

I have 3 entity managers in my symfony project and I want to add new table to a specific entity manager.
I know I can do this from command line by passing `--em="EntityManager1"` using the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:migration:migrate --em="EntityManager1"
```

**but I want to this in the code itself.**

example:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");�
    $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
             `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
             `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
             `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1�");
}

public function down(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql"); 
    $this->addSql("DROP TABLE myTable");�
}
```

Answer (score 6):

According to https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/38

You must implements `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface`

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class Version20140717170412 extends AbstractMigration implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
```

Then

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function up(Schema $schema)
{

    $myEmConnection = $this->container->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager('my_em')->getConnection();

    $this->skipIf(
        $this->connection !== $myEmConnection,
        'Require my_em manager'
    );
```